# message on a page depending on the location

Tags: php, wordpress, localization

It is possible to place a variable in a WordPress page, perhaps with shortcode or not, and that this change depending on the location of the person, if in the country1 is text1, if country2 = texto2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the aim behind changing those variables? are you looking to show different text based on location or use it to split test pages?

these plugins may help you to display different content as per geo.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-by-country/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/geotargeting/

Comment: Thanks Yasir ,It's just what I needed

Thank you so much, have a great day